# Can we say in first order logic the following: Every person who loves everyone is good?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have just started to learn the first order logic. I have learned that one can use predicated to specify relations between specific objects (or entities).

For example: $LocatedIn(Berlin, Germany)$

I have also learned that we can make statements like that:

$\exists x_1, \forall x_2. P(x_1, x_2, c_1)$

So, we have a "statement" and then instead of concrete objects we use variables and say that the statement is true for all (or at least one) arguments.

But can we use first order logic to express the following statement:

```
Every person who loves everyone is good.
```

So, I imagine something like that:

$\forall x_1. (Love(x_1, \forall x_2) \implies Good(x_1))$

But I think it is an invalid expression (because quantifier is insider of a predicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express "$x$ loves everyone" with the formula $\forall y\, Loves(x,y)$, assuming, as we will in this example, that variables range over people only. You can express "if $x$ loves everyone then $x$ is good" with the formula $\forall y\, Loves(x,y) \to Good(x)$. [*Note: the scope of $\forall y$ is **only** Loves(x,y), and doesn't extend to $Good(x)$.*] Thus, "every person who loves everyone is good" can be represented by
$$
\forall x\,(\forall y\, Loves(x,y) \to Good(x)).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in assuming the formula is invalid because of the presence of a quantifier inside a predicate. The following formula captures the essence of your English sentence: $$\forall x_1 (\forall x_2 (\mathop{\mathrm{Love}}(x_1,x_2)) \rightarrow \mathop{\mathrm{Good}}(x_1)).$$

Comment: the first sentence from your example says: For any x1 and x2, if x1 loves x2, then x1 is good. So, if x1 loves someone, then x1 is good. I think it is not what I want to say. For example if Jane loves Michael, we can say that Jane is good but in my example to be classified as good one has to love everyone (not just someone=.

Comment: how would you distinguish between: "If x1 loves someone, x1 is good" and "If x1 loves everyone, x1 is good"?

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Roman and BrianO. Careless mistakes are one of the disadvantages of browsing SE at 4 AM.